# R function definition difficulties

Tags: r

I have a vector of fish weight. I have written a function to check on the weight of the fish in the vector. If the weight is above 20, then update y (i.e., fish count) and z (i.e., fish total lbs). Below is the code:

```
function(x, y, z) {
  for (fish in 1:x) {
    if (x >= 20) {
      y <- y + 1
      z <- z + 1
      return (y, z)
    }
  }
}
```

When I call the function with

```
funcy_fish(BF_caught, BF_kept_ct, BF_kept_lbs)
```

I get multiple error messages but no optimal return; I want the variables to be updated with the fish count kept and the total lbs of fish kept. The error messages:

```
funcy_fish(BF_caught, BF_kept_ct, BF_kept_lbs)
[1] 1
Warning messages:
1: In 1:x : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
2: In if (x >= 20) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Please advise.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the function, and got the right output. But now, the variables I passed to the function are not updated:

```
> # function to determine which fish from caught var to keep
> funcy_fish <- function(x, y, z) {
+   y <- y + (sum(x > 20))
+   z <- z + (x %>% sum())
+   return (c(y, z))
+   # return (z)
+ }

> funcy_fish(BF_caught, BF_kept_ct, BF_kept_lbs)
[1]   4.0000 190.8728
```

The output is right, but BF_kept_ct and BF_kept_lbs are not updated in the global scope.

Comment: Why are you using a loop? `bigfish <- sum(x >= 20)` will give you the number of fish with a weight (x) over 20. Just add that to `y` and `z`.

Comment: @dcarlson I have a vector of fish that the function will be going over. For example, I have a vector of sharks, dolphins, etc. The for-loop is for each element in those lists...

Comment: Please provide a little bit of sample input in a copypasteable format, e.g., `dput(BF_caught[1:10])`

Comment: @GregorThomas > BF_caught
[1] 33.05791 79.50263 47.86284 30.44937

Comment: With functional programming in general, and R in particular, you shouldn't expect functions to modify global variables. If you want to change a variable `foo` in the global scope, then you assign the new value in the global scope  `foo <- my_function(foo)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a named list from the function -

```
funcy_fish <- function(x, y, z) {
     y <- y + (sum(x > 20))
     z <- z + (x %>% sum())
     return(list(BF_kept_ct = y, BF_kept_lbs = z))
}
res <- funcy_fish(BF_caught, BF_kept_ct, BF_kept_lbs)
```

If you want to update original `BF_kept_ct` and `BF_kept_lbs` variable use `list2env`.

```
list2env(res, .GlobalEnv)
```